# Ошибка при импорте файла в БД через pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql

Импортирую файл .csv в базу через pgAdmin4, причем ругается на некоторые строки.
Если эти строки удалить - данные грузятся.

Ошибка следующая:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8e
> ```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: какая кодировка базы?

Comment: кодировка базы UTF8